# Which are all the statements will lead to commit in a PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, commit, oracle11gr2

I'd written a PL/SQL procedure in Oracle 11g. I don't have `truncate`, `create` or `commit` statements but the session is still getting committed. I'm using SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer.

Can someone tell me which statements lead to a commit inside a procedure or function?

Comment: maybe the session in which you are calling the procedure is set to auto commit?

Comment: @tbone thanks for responding... I found the reason, i.e. Am using gather statistics after performing some dml operations. So it got commited.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thaks for responding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All DML statements (INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE/MERGE) don't commit in PL/SQL.

All DDL statements **do commit** (ALTER/CREATE...), even if the statement fails. If you're running a dynamic statement (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) that runs a DDL, this will also commit your transaction.

Some [DBMS packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/toc.htm) also have procedures that commit, for example [DBMS_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_stats.htm#CIHBIEII). It would be quite cumbersome to list them all. Read the appropriate documentation when you're using a DBMS package.

Comment: saved me many hours right here..
apparently altering sequences also counts as DDL :/